# How to configure package.json to generate HTML report in jest(I am not using jest.config.json file)

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I am working on testing rest API's for an node application. I have many test suites, so i want to generate an html report for the tests, I have installed jest-html-reporter. But i don't know how to configure in package.json( I am not using jest.config.json file)

package.json

```
{
  "name": "products_api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest-html-reporter": "^2.5.0",
    "joi": "^14.3.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.2.5",
    "redis": "^2.8.0",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "util": "^0.12.0"
  }
}
```